# How to print different language switching links depending on the current language in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, multilingual, drupal-theming

I am willing to create a custom language switcher that will print out only the language which is not currently active. I don't know how to link to the front page of a specific language or to translation of the current content/path.

Below is my code with the problem I'm facing:

```
global $language; 
 $lang=$language->language;
 $variables['languagelink']=''; 

 if($lang=="en") {
    $variables['languagelink']=l(t("Arabic"),'HERE I DONT KNOW HOW TO LINK TO ARABIC FRONT PAGE OR THE TRANSLATION OF THE CURRENT CONTENT');
 } elseif($lang=="ar") {
    $variables['languagelink']=l(t("English"),'HERE I DONT KNOW HOW TO LINK TO ENGLISH FRONT PAGE OR THE TRANSLATION OF THE CURRENT CONTENT');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way to do that is to hide the current language link with CSS. Usually the body has a specific class like `language-en` or `i18n-en` etc. using that, build your appropriate css selector to hide the current language link

Comment: Thanks Marius .... But what is the link with the l function to the language default page ? I am not generating the links from the language switching block ....

Comment: as I said, all the work should be done from CSS. you should not write any module for that. I've done that many times in the past. just use the default language switching block and hide the current language link with CSS. Take a look [here](http://www.redescoperaromania.ro/). You'll se the **English** link at the top of the screen, but not the **Romanian** one

Comment: Thanks! Just for my info how can I link to the default page of the specific website language?

Comment: I can't think of anything right now. I guess you could do some SQL interrogations to extract it from the database